# Rails Seeding an Enum Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, seed

So I have a model `Post` that has an enum declared in the model like so:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum draft_status: [:draft,:published]
```

I'm using Rails 4, It works fine everywhere except in my seeds.rb file.

```
post =Post.create!(user: user, content: "lorem ipsum", draft_status: 1)
```

Whenever I run db:seed I get the same error:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute
>   `draft_status`

I even tried doing this:

```
post =Post.create!(user: user, content: "lorem ipsum", draft_status: 1)
post.published!
```

I still get the same error. The migration exists and I can see the attribute in the schema. Further, every call in my console to `@post.draft_status` works and calling `@post.published!`also works. Why can't I seed in this enums attribute?

UPDATE: 
So it will seed my integer values if I run `rake db:setup`. My understanding is that the difference between rake db:setup and rake db:seed is that rake db:setup just creates the db `db:create`, loads the schema `db:schema:load` and then does a regular `db:seed`.